# Open component in a new tab

Tags: reactjs

I'm pretty new to React. I want to open a form on a new tab on a click of a button. Say Component2 renders the form template; What I want to achieve is open this form provided in Component2 when a button in component1 is clicked.

I have tried using Router, but I'm not quite sure if I've done it the right way

[image: Approach taken]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, it's much appreciated to include actual code as text instead of posting a picture.

Comment: Am I heading the right direction or is there an easier approach. Any guidance would be really helpful.

Comment: please provide the code referenced by this.CreateTicket

Comment: @Broom : the following is the code referenced by CreateTicket:

 CreateTicket() {
    this.setState({issueForm: true});
    
  }

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode and [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Wrap this button by Link component simple give prop to=''path''       <Link to="/ticket/create"><button> click </button> </Link>

Comment: @NikhilPatil - Thanks!! this really helped in achieving what I wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into [React Portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html), which allow you to retain shared state with your parent component across tabs or even across windows.